# Difference between an azure virtual machine and node

Tags: azure

I happen to read this [about ACL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-acl)
"traffic from remote IP addresses is filtered by the host node instead of on your VM. This prevents your VM from spending the precious CPU cycles"

since VM's CPU cycles are saved by node, where does node reside? 
Isn't node another name for VM?
Doesn't node reside inside VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About ACL, it's the classic model on Azure and now the Azure Resource Manager model is more recommended.

The host node means the physical server which supports the VM running on it. The traffic to the VM will come in from the Internet through the network interface of the host node. When you create the VM, there is a location would be chosen and that's the region where the host node in.

Comment: aren't ACL and ARM completely different things? Why do we mention ARM as a replacement for ACL?

Comment: @BlueClouds Yeah, they do the same thing, just different in manage model on Azure. You can get more details about these two model from [Azure Resource Manager vs. classic deployment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-model).

Comment: So host node uses the CPU cycles and memory of physical server(not VM), correct?

Comment: @BlueClouds Yes.